# Node.js Cluster - detect worker stuck?

Tags: linux, node.js, cluster-computing

I'm using node.js with cluster, typically with 2 cpu's which translate to one master and two workers.
I am having a sneaky problem, where occasionaly (very rarely), one of the workers gets 'stuck'
for some reason, and the other bares all of the load.
I am not sure of the cause and still investigating (no memory leak, no stack overflow, no exception).

When looking at the processes using top bash command on linux, I can clearly see that one of the node processes is steady at 100% cpu load.

What I want to ask of you guys today, is whether you know of a way to detect this situation (when one worker is at 100%) so I can kill it off.

Answer (score 2):

OK,
So here goes.
Turns out my worker gets absolutely stuck. Don't know why, but it may be a cluster problem (what you call a cluster %^&$)
Anyway, I had to monitor workers by the master.
What I did is use cron to report from each worker every minute to the master, like so:

process.send({id:cluster.worker.id})

The master would receive that message and know that this worker is alive and well.
The master then keeps a count of missing worker responses. After 5 minutes, the worker is killed if the count reaches 0 (decremented once every minute)

This is how I achieved (my own) goal of killing a stuck worker after a few minutes.
This is not a complete solution, and I still don't know what causes the workers to get stuck without any exception.
But that is life right now.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [usage](https://www.npmjs.org/package/usage) package.
Something like this should work. I skipped cluster and worker setup.

```
var usage = require('usage');    
setInterval(function() {
    usage.lookup(worker.process.pid, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if(result.cpu > 90){
            worker.kill();
        }
    });
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Actually this didn't work, since this relies on the worker to do the reporting. What happens in my case is that the worker gets absolutely stuck and stops reporting. I am adding as an answer what I reverted to

Comment: Actually I have a similar case with the Postgresql module where it was running out of clients and cleaning them was not enough, and I implemented a similar solution. After I responded, I also noticed that the result.cpu is not working correctly with Mac OSX. Were you testing it on Mac or Linux? I am curious if the logic was not working due to Mac.